# Confused about "total derivative"

Tags: derivatives, soft-question, definition

I'm confused about "total derivative", and looking around, I'm not the only one.

I have seen this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174272/290307 .

This answer is obviously flawed by not distinguishing "function" and "expression",

The function has fixed positions for $x$ and $y$, for $f:\;\;\mathbb R\times \mathbb R\,\mapsto \mathbb R$, whereas the *expression*, something like $2x+3y$, without the whereabouts of $x$ and $y$, has not.

I am looking for a **solid** definition of the total derivative, not what it is used like colloquially.

Comment: See the answer I've written [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3844684/688539)

Comment: I don't understand why the difference of function vs. expression comes up.  Seems to have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Anyway, the total derivative is a linear transformation (or equivalently, a matrix). Any good answer would have to use those tools.  Are you familiar with them?

Comment: In what generality do you want to have the definition? In euclidean space or general Banach spaces?

Comment: @Randall I have a degree in math, but I'm decades out of practice.

Comment: The clearest definition/discussion I've seen is in Baby Rudin.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven finite real vector spaces would be good enough for a start. More is always welcome, but I can't give a guaranty that I would have understanding of it.

Comment: @Randall "The clearest definition/discussion I've seen is in Baby Rudin." Could you spare a link to it? My google search (newly requiring me to allow data collection totally monitoring me, and you) did not come up with relevant results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open, nonempty set, $f: U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a function and $x_0\in U$ some point. We say that $f$ is (Frechet-)differentiable in $x_0$ if there exists a linear function $L_x: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ such that
$$ \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\Vert f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)-L_x(h) \Vert_{\mathbb{R}^m}}{\Vert h \Vert_{\mathbb{R}^n}} =0.$$
In this case we call $L_x$ the total derivative of $f$ at the point $x_0$. Usually we write $Df(x_0)$ instead of $L_x$.

So what is this total derivative? It is the best "linear approximation". I.e. if you want to fit some linear function at $f$ in $x_0$, then you want to pick the total derivative. How is this related to the "usual" derivative we see in college? If we have $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is differentiable in $x_0$, then $g'(x_0)$ is the slope of the tangent at $g$ in $x_0$. This line is the best fit you can have at $g$ in $x_0$. In one dimension the line is uniquely determined by its slope (and the fact that it has to go through $(x_0,g(x_0))$. Hence, there is the following correspondence between derivative and total derivative in one dimension: $g'(x_0)= Dg(x_0)[1]$. Or in other words
$$ Dg(x_0):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, Dg(x_0)[h] = g'(x_0) \cdot h.  $$